Как определить что сайт открыт в новом браузере Телеграм?
Недавно с обновлением Телеграма вышел их браузер в котором не мало косяков, есть ли какая то возможность или может у кого идея определить что сайт открыт именно в нём? userAgent ничего особенного не предлагает и там зацепиться не за что.

Пробуй проверить свойство window.Telegram читал что "Далее необходима проверка на существование этого объекта, так как если данное приложение будет запущено не внутри мессенджера, то объект определен не будет"... https://infostart.ru/1c/articles/1999597/

Серверными средствами по заголовкам никак, но вы можете внедрить в свою страницу/сайт простенький js-код который займется этим. Из полезных зацепок, если будете проверять со стороны клиента — sessionStorage в котором хранятся всяческие переменные среди которых есть и цветовая палитра.
